# Calculate row means in R

Tags: r, mean

Sorry if this question is duplicated, I've been searching everywhere and can't seem to find the answer.
This is my code:

```
datos=read_delim("~/Downloads/estaciones.csv",";",trim_ws = TRUE)
mensual <- datos %>% group_by(X1) %>% arrange((X1))
names(mensual)[2:33]<-"1":"32"
mensual [83,2:33]=0
mensual [123,2:33]=0
mensual [135,2:33]=0
mensual [137:138,2:33]=0
mensual [140,2:33]=0
mensual [149:155,2:33]=0
mensual [166:172,2:33]=0
mensual [103:105,2:33]=0
mensual [223:224,2:33]=0
mensual [295,2:33]=0
mensual [191,2:33]=0
mensual$mean <- rowMeans(mensual, na.rm=TRUE)
```

But when I run it, it says:
`Error in rowMeans(mensual, na.rm = TRUE) : 'x' debe ser num'erico`

Can you help me please? I need to add a last column with mean from the rows' values, with `NA` values taken into consideration. I mean, if I have 33 values and 21 `NA`, when it calculates means it should consider 33 values and 21 from those values are zeros.

[image]

Comment: You could use the `is.na` function to help you convert NA to 0. Something  like `mensual[is.na(mensual[:2]] <- 0`. It would help if you posted a sample of data. It seems you meant to in the "Portion of my data" section.

Comment: Daniel, thank you for your answer, just added a link. The problem is that it's rainfall data, so it's different having zero and having na, the first one would mean there's no rain and the second one means there's no data. For mean proposes, having no data is like having zeros, but i do not want to replace all of them. Is there any other way? If not, i'll just do that. Thank you very much!

Comment: Completely understand the 0 vs no data issue. You seem to be overwriting some data with 0 on many of the lines of your question i.e. `mensual [135,2:33]=0`. My comment was based on this (assuming you were trying to mask the na's as zero) and given your statement: "I mean, if I have 33 values and 21 NA, when it calculates means it should consider 33 values and 21 from those values are zeros." - which sounds like you want NA converted to zero for the purpose of the mean (rather than being dropped out and not factored into the mean).

Comment: Still have the same error described above: Error in rowMeans(mensual[, -1], na.rm = TRUE) : 'x' debe ser num'erico. Changed na for zeros and no luck :(

Comment: Flor - it would help to include the output of `str(mensual)` in your post so we can see if there are other string or non-numeric data types in the data set. It is likely your data set has another column (other than the first) that is non-numeric.

Answer (score 3):

Hard to know for sure but perhaps you haven't removed X1 from the rowMeans argument? I'd try:

```
 mensual$myRmean <- rowMeans( mensual[-1], na.rm=TRUE)
```

It's truly an unwise strategy to name data objects or columns with the same name as an important R function.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion. Just tried what you said and the result is the same:     mensual$myRmean <- rowMeans( mensual[-1], na.rm=TRUE), Error in rowMeans(mensual[-1], na.rm = TRUE) : 'x' debe ser num'erico

Comment: I think @42- is right but there might be a `,` missing in `mensual[,-1]`

`mensual$myRmean <- rowMeans( mensual[,-1], na.rm=TRUE)`

give it a shot

Comment: Thank you guys, still the same mistake anyway: Error in rowMeans(mensual[, -1], na.rm = TRUE) : 'x' debe ser num'erico.

Comment: You need to post AT A MINIMUM the results of `str(mensual)`. That picture you posted suggest the remaining columns were numeric but there may be a data entry error that is not apparent.